# Is it possible to run a function when a user hits a key combination

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that I would like to association with a key combination, like CTRL+ALT+D.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please give more details...in which context? In a doc, a UI,???

Comment: @Sergeinsas is it possible in any context at all?

Comment: nope ! (at least not that I know and I'm pretty sure about it...) but it's always good to know what the author has in mind ;-)

Answer (score 0):

not possible from any of the google apps that support apps script. there is an issue on the spps script issue tracker asking for this.
you might be able to do this from a htmlService web app using regular Javascript events (if caja allows it).
you can also write a browser extension and implement calling menu items (of apps script menus inside drive apps) by pressing key combinations.